# Responsive size while using bootstrap

Tags: html, iframe, bootstrap-4

I want to keep a text editor(textarea) and an iframe in the two columns of a single row using bootstrap and here is HTML code for the same.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
            <iframe id="renderHTML" srcdoc="" class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am facing is that the size of both textarea and iframe is very small and I don't want to specify the width and height of the two explicitly as the design won't remain responsive. What may be the solution to increase the sizes of the two and keep the design respomsive.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewport units:

1vw = 1% of the width of the page
1vh = 1% of the height of the page

You can use it the same way as pixels but than it's responsive.

Example:

```
<iframe src="http://example.com" width="50vw" height="50vw"></iframe>
```

This iframe is equal to 50% of the page width and height.

Comment: It became even smaller when I applied this.

Answer (score 0):

the `col` classes look invalid, try this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div id="editor"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
            <iframe id="renderHTML" srcdoc="" class="embed-responsive-item"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```